# while uploading multiple images error occur says data could not updated

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, upload

i am trying to make multiple image uploader with data conectivity so the image name should be saved in database , now when i am uploading image it is uploading and also showing in folder but not uploading in my database and says ***Sorry Data Could Not Updated !***

please help me i have tried for 1 day . here is my uploading code

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
require_once 'common_functions.php';

if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    $msg = "";
    if (count($_FILES["user_files"]) > 0) {
        $folderName = "uploads/";
        $counter = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) {

            $file_name=$_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i];

            if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {
                $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
                $file_name = $folderName . rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;
                $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'); // valid extensions
                if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)){  
                    $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                    $newFileName=$filename.$ext;
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i],"Uploads/".$newFileName)) {
                        $msg .= "Failed to upload" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . ". <br>";
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    if(!isset($msg)) {
                        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO products SET productname=:productname');
                        $stmt->bindParam(':productname',$newFileName);
                        if($stmt->execute()){

                            $msg = "Your Post ' ".$newFileName." ' has been successfully uploaded , <a  target='_blank'   href='post.php?name=".$newFileName." '>View</a>.";

                            // redirects video view page after 5 seconds.
                        } else {
                            $msg = "error while inserting....";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $msg = "Sorry Data Could Not Updated !";
                    }
                } else {
                    $msg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG  files are allowed.";        
                }
            }
        }
    }


} else {
    $msg = errorMessage("You must upload atleast one file");
}
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "SET" in an "INSERT" statement. Try ...

```
'INSERT INTO products (productname) VALUES (:productname)'
```

In the future, you can save yourself a day or so by triggering a MySQLi error and displaying:

```
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: "SET" is used for the "UPDATE" statement  ( UPDATE products SET productname = :produstname WHERE .... )